# Is there any better way to get rid of Directory traversal attack?

Tags: java

I am trying to prevent Directory traversal attack on my project and I don't understand what is wrong with this

```
public static final String validateOnDiskFilePath(final String absoluteFolderPath, final String child) {
    String absolutePath = null;
    try {
        String filePath = absoluteFolderPath + File.separator +child;
        absolutePath = new File(absoluteFolderPath, child).getCanonicalPath();
        if (!absolutePath.startsWith(filePath)) {
            throw new SecureStorageException(MessageFormat.format("Invalid path constructed! path ={0}, absolutePath ={1}", filePath, absolutePath));
        }
    }catch(IOException ie){
        throw new SecureStorageException("Failed to get the absolutePath", ie);
    }
    return absolutePath;
}

public static final String validateOnDiskFilePath(final String absoluteFolderPath) {
    String absolutePath = null;
    try {
        absolutePath = new File(absoluteFolderPath).getCanonicalPath();
        if (!absolutePath.startsWith(absoluteFolderPath)) {
            throw new SecureStorageException(MessageFormat.format("Invalid path constructed! path ={0}, absolutePath ={1}", absoluteFolderPath, absolutePath));
        }
    }catch(IOException ie){
        throw new SecureStorageException("Failed to get the absolutePath", ie);
    }
    return absolutePath;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think something is wrong? What happens when you run your code? What do you want it to do differently?

Comment: I have written some test cases and this code always throws an exception with Invalid path constructed @Code-Apprentice

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].